# Load IP Whitelist into Salesforce via API

Tags: api, whitelisting

I have a list of around 412 whitelist records to load into the Network Access section of Security Controls in my org.  With so many IP addresses to load, is there any way to load this programmatically into Salesforce?

I haven't found a way to do this through my research at this time.

Answer (score 4):

There is an app called [Trusted IP Ranges](https://login.salesforce.com/?ec=302&startURL=%2Fpackaging%2FinstallPackage.apexp%3Fp0%3D04tF0000000JHh6)(install link) that uses JavaScript to add all possible ranges. You could modify the code to use your list. The code is available here on [Github](https://github.com/rdehler/IP-Ranges).

Comment: Link to the Blog post on the tool: [Enable All Trusted IP Ranges for a Salesforce Org](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/enable-all-trusted-ip-ranges-for-a-salesforce-org.html)

Comment: Unofrtunately with Summer '15 platform release, it doesn't work anymore. I've createa tool unofrtunately without the same autonation, due to cross-domain limits, here: http://blog.enree.co/2015/08/salesforce-revamp-enable-all-trusted-ip.html

Comment: There's now a Chrome plugin to accomplish this. http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/whitelist-all-ips-for-salesforce-chrome-extension.html